# Android GPs location tracker

Tags: java, android

I want an Android app that will take user coordinates and send them to another app which will be in turn shown on a map. I can get my location on the map, but how so I send it to the other app?

Please help?

Comment: how about add your location to a List with a Timestamp?

Comment: Where is your other app in the same device ?

Comment: what is the name of the other app? Did you download it from Play Store?

Comment: there will be two parts of my app. parent and child. child location will be sent automatically to the parent which will be on the other device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send info to some other device then it might be easiest to store location data in a remote database, and the other app can retrieve the data from that database. 
I suggest to look up for some tutorials on SQL database with PHP script service (like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm). There are a plenty of free mySQL database hosting sites.

Comment: Easier way still would be using firebase real time databasehttps://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send data directly from an app on one device to an app on another device in the use case of gps tracking. You will need some sort of server/database to be able to do this.

Google has Firebase real time database that is free if you're not using much data for example. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: i want to make the parent app act as server.

Comment: I want to make a child monitoring app. the app will have two parts. one will be the child and the other will be parent. what i want is to make child location sent to the parent app on request.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to achiev. The problem is that the parent app doesn't have a fixed IP address assuming that you want to be able to carry the phone with you and connect to different networks? Therefor the parent app cannot be a server.

Comment: i want to connect that with phone number sir.

Comment: You can't target a phone as a server based on phone number. What you could do is send a SMS from the parent phone, build a broadcast receiver on the child phone that uses [link] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html) and send a SMS back with the location.

Comment: requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},112);

Comment: this line is giving an error. i am using this code for marshmallow. min sdk 18 and max 23. whats the problem in this code.

Answer (score 0):

this is the method for showing current location. i want to send the coordinate to a local server and then to get on another app. please write me some code i m new to android.

```
enter code here

          public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat =location.getLatitude();
            lng=location.getLongitude();
            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("I am here").position(position));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15f));
           // Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Respond me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
```